# FB Like comment box-meta tag not showing up below the comment box

Tags: comments, facebook-like

When I click the like button on my site, it opens up the comment box but its not populating the meta info there (title, link,image, description) but after I like and refresh the page, then unlike and like it again at that time it opens the comment box with all the meta info.

so basically each time when I like for the first time it's not displaying it. any idea? its a ecommerce site I am working on, and the user likes the product on that site. each product has its own like button.

Appreciate your help.

thanks

Comment: What happens when you lint the url?